# How do I specify an action's default model

Tags: php, yii

I want to make an action's model to be the current user's if not specified. How to do that?

For example, I have an profile action in user controller. If the url is like /user/profile/3 , It will show profile of user whose id is 3 and if the url is like /user/profile it will show the current user's.

```
public function actionProfile($id){
                   $model=$this->loadModel($id);
                   $this->render('profile',array(
                        'model'=>$model
                ));
        }
```

Comment: in your function, if $id is empty, set `$id = Yii::app()->user->id`? Is that what you mean? It's not entirely clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @ldg $id is the parameter of this function if you don't specify it it's an fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public function actionProfile($id=null)
{
    $id=($id===null?Yii::app()->user->id:$id);
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are talking about [default scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar).

In the model:

```
public function defaultScope ()
{
    if (Yii::app ()->user->id)
    {
        return array (
            'condition' => 'user_id=' . Yii::app ()->user->id,
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // or whatever
        return array ();
    }
}
```

Then any query in your controller will use that as a condition.